# Переключение между Fragments в Navigation Drawer

Tags: drawerlayout, android, java

Добрый день.

Понемногу изучаю разработку приложений под Android. И вот решил разобраться с NavigationDrawer. Создал новый проект в Eclipse и выбрал тип навигации Drawer. Только вот пока не могу разобраться, как переключатся между фрагментами. То есть, допустим, есть у меня два созданных мною xml-файла fragment1 и fragment2, хочу сделать, чтобы первый загружался при запуске приложения, а второй при нажатии на пункт меню из Drawer.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что и где нужно изменить, либо поделитесь ссылкой на урок или мануал по этому Drawer, поскольку мои поиски ни к чему не привели, а все примеры, которые были найдены, вовсе не похожи на Drawer, который создается при создании нового проекта в Eclipse.   Спасибо.

Вот код из MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,
                        PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере используется класс PlaceholderFragment, который инфлейтит R.layout.fragment_main.
В Вашем случае нужно создать свои собственные классы для фрагментов

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)
```

Этот метод переключает фрагменты (по нажатию на элемент drawer`a). (position - позиция элемента на который нажали 1,2...)

```
  public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber)
```

Этот метод возвращает фрагмент, для того чтобы его *заинфлейтить* ("inflate" - раздуть).

Обычно я справляюсь с такой задачей вот таким образом, но это не самый лучший способ:

```
 final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT = "text";
    final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE = "image";
    SimpleAdapter sAdapter;
    ListView lvSimple;
    Fragment f;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_window);

        initActionBar();
        String[] titles = {
                getString(R.string.strDrawerItem1),
                getString(R.string.strDrawerItem2),
                getString(R.string.strDrawerItem3),
                getString(R.string.strDrawerItem4),
                getString(R.string.strDrawerItem5)
        };

        int icons[] = {
                R.drawable.drawer_ic_payments,
                R.drawable.drawer_ic_internal_transfers,
                R.drawable.drawer_ic_to_another_client,
                R.drawable.drawer_ic_acc_transfer_client,
                R.drawable.drawer_ic_transfers_russia
        };

        // упаковываем данные в понятную для адаптера структуру
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                titles.length);
        Map<String, Object> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, titles[i]);
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE, icons[i]);
            data.add(m);
        }

        // массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
        String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT,
                ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE };
        // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
        int[] to = { textViewName, imageViewIcon };

        // создаем адаптер
          sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.list_item_1,
                from, to);

        // определяем список и присваиваем ему адаптер
        lvSimple = (ListView) findViewById(drawer_list);
        lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);

        lvSimple.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

                switch (position){
                        case 0:
                            f = new PaymentsMainFragment();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            f = new InternalTransferFragment();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            f = new ToClientCardFragment();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            f = new ToClientAccountFragment();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            f = new RussiaTransfersFragment();
                            break;
                        default:

                                break;
                    }
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, f);

                ft.commit();

            }
        });

    }
```